# Passing a value from a select statement into a function inside the same query - SQL , SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SQL query like this for me to use in the SSRS .

```
Select Id ,
       Name ,
       (SELECT RecordNumber FROM dbo.GetLinkedRecordsByType(DTI.TYPEID, DT.ProjectID) AS          
         doctype WHERE      (Id = DTI.SourceId)) AS LinkedDocNo,
       etc,etc .. From Table_name .
```

Now I have condition that I need to pass the value of **LinkedDocNo**  into another function in the same query as a subquery . something like this

```
dbo.WBS_GetNodePath(LinkedDocNo) .
```

But I know I cant pass it like i have done above. Kindly suggest me a way to achieve it .

Comment: why you cant pass it? `dbo.WBS_GetNodePath(SELECT RecordNumber FROM dbo.GetLinkedRecordsByType(DTI.TYPEID, DT.ProjectID) AS doctype WHERE      (Id = DTI.SourceId))` should work

Comment: I tried but i am getting a syntax error . Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: what if something like this `select dbo.WBS_GetNodePath(LinkedDocNo) from (Select Id , Name , (SELECT RecordNumber FROM dbo.GetLinkedRecordsByType(DTI.TYPEID, DT.ProjectID) AS doctype WHERE (Id = DTI.SourceId)) AS LinkedDocNo,...) as q`

Comment: Nope :( It says unable to parse query ..

Comment: Any other suggestions guys ??? am struck with this ...

Comment: Sorry man . your first suggestion was right ! I made a mistake while i executed. Thanks for it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, why dont you try the following: 
- it is valid only if your function is table-valued

```
,select 'column_name' from dbo.WBS_GetNodePath((SELECT RecordNumber FROM  dbo.GetLinkedRecordsByType(DTI.TYPEID, DT.ProjectID) AS          
     doctype WHERE (Id = DTI.SourceId)))
```

Or try exactly the same without:

```
--'column_name' from

    ,select dbo.WBS_GetNodePath((SELECT RecordNumber FROM  dbo.GetLinkedRecordsByType(DTI.TYPEID, DT.ProjectID) AS          
     doctype WHERE (Id = DTI.SourceId)))
```